# Text Edit Change Variable Names

Tags: python, regex, perl, text

Cleaning up variables for a program in work, 100s of violations to clean up all with the same issue. For example:

```
var m_thisExample,
```

and I want `var mThisExample`

(All start with m_)

Is there anyway to script this rather than hours of find/replace?
Thanks,
Reggie.

Comment: Sure there is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Open a file, read the text, do a replace on it, write the text to the file, save the file. Which of these steps are you having difficulty with?

Comment: `sed -i.bak -e 's/var m_/var m/g' filename` will do the first bit. You probably want `tr` for the second, because you're transliterating.

Comment: @Sobrique You don't need to use tr command. see my answer.

Comment: @Regi did you want to replace `var m_63` also?

Comment: I would suggest asking this over on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may catch a few false matches, but this is the jist of it. It backs up the original files by adding a `.bak` extension, but *make sure* you have your own backup before overwriting valuable code.

I assume these are JavaScript files?

```
perl -i.bak -pe's/\bm_(\w)/m\u$1/g' *.js
```